# Timestamp to specific format - ex: 2014-11-04T09:10:33.000Z (PHP)

Tags: php, timestamp

Does anyone knows how to convert a timestamp to the following format?

```
 2014-11-04T09:10:33.000Z
```

I can't find any examples around this.
Looking forward to hear from you! :-)

Comment: Do you know the regular way we convert timestamps to various formats?

Comment: echo date("y-m-d\TH:i.s \Z ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z",time());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Example:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1299446702);
```